# How do you test PL/SQL code such as the following?

Tags: sql, testing, plsql

I need to test out a PLSQL Package that  consists mainly of executing stored procedures.

The package body code is as follows :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY 
IS
   PROCEDURE VERIFY_HCSL_PACKAGES
     IS
     BEGIN

     exec j645.HCSL_Verify.Check_Object('j645', 'CG$APP_MODULE_ROLES', 'PACKAGE BODY');
     exec j645.HCSL_Verify.Check_Object('j645', 'CG$APP_PARAMETERS', 'PACKAGE');
     exec j645.HCSL_Verify.Check_Object('j645', 'CG$APP_PARAMETERS', 'PACKAGE BODY');
     exec j645.HCSL_Verify.Check_Object('j645', 'CG$APP_ROLES', 'PACKAGE');
     exec j645.HCSL_Verify.Check_Object('j645', 'CG$APP_ROLES', 'PACKAGE BODY');
     exec j645.HCSL_Verify.Check_Object('j645', 'CG$APP_USERS', 'PACKAGE');
     exec j645.HCSL_Verify.Check_PkgSpec('S735', 'ACTIVATE', 'PVCS $Revision:   124.1');
     exec j645.HCSL_Verify.Check_Object('j645', 'CG$APP_USERS', 'PACKAGE BODY');
     exec j645.HCSL_Verify.Check_Object('j645', 'CG$BAG_DEVICE_PARMS', 'PACKAGE');
     exec j645.HCSL_Verify.Check_Object('j645', 'CG$BAG_DEVICE_PARMS', 'PACKAGE BODY');
     exec j645.HCSL_Verify.Check_Object('j645', 'CG$BAG_IDS', 'PACKAGE');
     exec j645.HCSL_Verify.Check_Object('j645', 'CG$BAG_IDS', 'PACKAGE BODY');
  END VERIFY_HCSL_PACKAGES;
END HCSL$UTIL_AA;
```

I want to create useful tests of the above code. How do you create something similar to a unit test with code such as the above?

Comment: Well, it would of course depend on what those stored procedures actually do. From the names, it sounds like they're doing some sort of data validation? Do each of those stored procedures have their own tests? Or are you trying to write a test for all of them at once?

Comment: @JoshEller  - They don't have their own tests.  I'm trying to test for all of them . Correct, these are data validations

Comment: So far ,  I have tried putting in DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE  statements to just confirm that code blocks were reached..

Comment: Generally, I would test a validation function by inserting bad data, and making sure it returns the correct error code. For each of the validation functions, you'd want at least one test for each category of bad data it's meant to check for, and at least one test with all good data. Just checking whether a block of code is reached isn't sufficient for unit testing; you need to make sure that the function actually performs according to expectation (ideally, the expectations would be documented in a functional spec or similar document).

Comment: @JoshEller  -   Understood ,  this is making sense to me now.  Will need to dive into the PLSQL code here,

Comment: Well `exec j645.HCSL_Verify.Check_Object('j645', 'CG$APP_MODULE_ROLES', 'PACKAGE BODY');` this is not a correct way of calling a procedure in a Oracle `PLSQL` block.  You need to remove `EXEC` before doing anything else.